# sessions are not working in codeignatior

Tags: codeigniter

**I am set the array data in to sessions and redirect to search_results page but its not get the data**

1. here i am set the data to sessions my sessions code is

   ```
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_flashdata('data',$results);
    redirect('search/search_results');
   ```
2. here retrive the sessions data code is

   ```
   $this->load->library('session');
   $myVar = $this->session->flashdata('data');
   print_r($myVar);
   ```
3. but its not print the data
4. thanks for advance

Comment: Codeigniter defualt store session data in cookies you can face the issue if size is more , better to store in DB.

Comment: Have you set the encryption key in **application/config/config.php**?

Comment: is it working if you using `$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');` instead of set_flashdata??

Comment: thanks prashant-thakret.i am delete the cache. its working without changes

Answer (score 0):

I remember having the same problem with CodeIgniter, I think a year ago. I had the wrong cookie prefix in the **application/config/config.php** file. You could try setting it to its default, like:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = ""; 
$config['cookie_domain'] = ""; 
$config['cookie_path']   = "/"; 
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
```

And then change it to your webserver settings if your webserver has other configuration.
CodeIgniter indeed stores session data in cookies as far as I know like *prashant thakre* mentioned in the comments on your question.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks ihsan.i am delete the cache. its working without changes

Comment: Oh right! Nice to hear.. I mean read that it's working again! :)
You could update the post by answering yourself and marking that as answered so this post won't be bumped.